# Amazon S3 Bucket not storing Spanish language characters correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I read that SES character encoding is set to  7-bit ASCII format by default. How can I configure my SES email service and associated S3 Bucket to store non-english characters sent by email correctly in the bucket? See example of the error below:

The email body text - notice the (í):

```
hola como estas como fue tu día mi amigo
```

How it's stored in S3:

```
hola como estas como fue tu d=C3=ADa mi amigo
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an error or misconfiguration.  The bucket and SES are working correctly.  SES stores the payload in the bucket exactly as received.

`=C3=AD` is the representation of `í` (U+00ED, utf8 bytes 0xC3 0xAD) in MIME [quoted-printable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) content transfer encoding, which is compatible with 7-bit ASCII for transmission purposes.

To extract this text for display elsewhere, you will need a library that properly handles MIME and can extract and convert the content.

Comment: Thanks this helped me understand my problem... When I started to use npm mailparser to parse email, I found that the libmime module within it started to do the decoding automatically for me.